# Multiple queries executed by Hibernate with @OneToOne and @JoinColumnsOrFormulas

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

I have a table that contains personal data. This can be referenced by different tables.

**PersonalData.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "personal_information")
@Getter
@Setter
public class PersonalInformation implements Serializable{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "personal_information_no")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "personal_information_seq")
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "personal_information_seq", sequenceName = "personal_information_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
   private int personalInformationNo;
   
   @Column(name = "ref_object_type")
   private String refObjectType;
   
   @Column(name = "ref_object_no")
   private int refObjectNo;

   @Column(name = "type")
   private String type;
}
```

**Staff.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "staff")
public class Staff {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "staff_no", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int staffNo;

@OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column =  @JoinColumn( name = "staff_no", referencedColumnName = "ref_object_no", insertable=false, updatable=false)),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula( value = "(SELECT 'staff')", referencedColumnName = "ref_object_type")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula( value = "(SELECT 'work')", referencedColumnName = "type"))
    })
    private PersonalInformation workPersonalInformation;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column =  @JoinColumn( name = "staff_no", referencedColumnName = "ref_object_no", insertable=false, updatable=false)),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula( value = "(SELECT 'staff')", referencedColumnName = "ref_object_type")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula( value = "(SELECT 'private')", referencedColumnName = "type"))
    })
    private PersonalInformation privatePersonalInformation;
}
```

**User.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class BusinessProviderUser {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "user_no", unique = true, nullable = false)
   private int userNo;

   @Column(name = "staff_no")
   private Integer staffNo;
    
   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
      @JoinColumnOrFormula(column =  @JoinColumn( name = "user_no", referencedColumnName = "ref_object_no", insertable=false, updatable=false)),
      @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula( value = "(SELECT 'user')", referencedColumnName = "ref_object_type"))
   })
   private PersonalInformation personalInformation;
}
```

As you can see, the reference is a bit more complex. This problem was solved with the annotation @JoinColumnsOrFormulas. The join to the person data is annotated @OneToOne in the referencing table.

The problem now is that each time the referencing table is called, additional queries are always executed.

How can I prevent this so that everything is executed in one query?

It is known that Hibernate does not support lazy loading with @OneToOne. One approach here was to implement lazy loading using bytecode enhencment. Unfortunately without success.

```java
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
   @JoinColumnOrFormula(column =  @JoinColumn( name = "user_no", referencedColumnName = "ref_object_no", insertable=false, updatable=false)),
   @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula( value = "(SELECT 'user')", referencedColumnName = "ref_object_type"))
})
private PersonalInformation personalInformation;
```

Another approach is to load everything in one single query by adding @Fetch(FetchMode.Join).

```java
@OneToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
   @JoinColumnOrFormula(column =  @JoinColumn( name = "user_no", referencedColumnName = "ref_object_no", insertable=false, updatable=false)),
   @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula( value = "(SELECT 'user')", referencedColumnName = "ref_object_type"))
})
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private PersonalInformation personalInformation;
```

In the end, it is not crucial for the project whether the data is loaded lazy (preferred) or immediately.

It is only important that multiple queries are not sent per user or staff.

Are there any tips or solutions for the problem?

Maybe there is also a nicer solution regarding the database structure? Changes could be made here as well.

Unfortunately, Hibernate version 3.6.10-final must still be used.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).